# Is it possible to check the Bell's block entity data?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

[Minecraft 1.14.4]

I want to check when a player hits a village bell in minecraft, and then perform some action.

After reading a bit on the minecraft wiki, it seems that bells have a block Entity Data entry named "keepPacked" that should be set to 1 if the bell is swaying (has been hit) or 0 if it's stationary.

I'm not sure how to access this data, or if this is even possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a scoreboard objective to detect when a player rings a bell, the command to create the scoreboard objective looks like this:

```
/scoreboard objectives add bell minecraft.custom:minecraft.bell_ring
```

The score for a player increases by one every time that player rings a bell.

Answer (score 1):

According to the wiki, `keepPacked` has something to do with world generation and is not specific to bells. So it is not a tag for having been rung by a player or not. There is also no other NBT tag specific to bells. (Honestly I wonder why it's a tile entity at all then.)
There is also no block state indicating whether a bell is or was ringing. So I assume that ringing a bell is just a specially coded event that instantly applies the effect to nearby mobs, plays the sound and the animation, but isn't stored anywhere. Leaving and re-joining the world during the bell animation would probably show an unmoving bell.

So, in summary: Commands cannot detect when a bell is ringing or has been rung.

Comment: If it's a tile entity, potentially can't be moved by pistons or similar? Probably done that way to prevent other bugs happening with adding/removing the bells from villager memory.  Haven't actually done too much testing on the newest version since it was changing a lot after release

Comment: If it was simply to not be movable by pistons, they could have just added it to the list of obsidian, bedrock, barriers, structure void, end portal frames, end portals, nether portals, ender chests, extended pistons, piston heads, enchantment tables and the three types of anvils.

Comment: Is there any block that is not a tile entity, but has an animation (animated textures and particles don't count)? As I understand it, the bell is a tile entity, because it has an animation.

Comment: I just went through the list of blocks and apparently you're somewhat right, many blocks have tile entities despite not needing them, like ender chests, conduit, dragon heads and extending piston bases.

Comment: https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-159902

Comment: I deleted my comments, because you got an answer in your link. Here is a shortened version: I think that I said almost the opposite of that, I meant that blocks with some kind of animation always are tile entities (unless you can think of some block where that isn't the case?). Ender chests open and close, activated conduits are animated, dragon heads are animated when powered, and piston heads extend and retract visually.

Comment: BTW, I learned more about this since these comments: Animated block models do indeed require a tile entity. Same for very variable things like signs or banners. There are still some blocks that have tile entities despite not needing them, but they are few, mainly just the non-dragon, non-player heads. Pistons and comparators are debatable.